# export variable that contains C struct from C++ DLL

Tags: c++, qt, dll, stl, dllexport

so i'm just getting my feet wet to dll stuff, in my case i'm trying to make a process listor with Qt as GUI
however i want this function to be stored in my dll and it contain C struct
but it seems doesn't work

here's some code in header file:

this is the struct**

```
extern "C" typedef struct MY_API _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION {
.....
.....
.....
LARGE_INTEGER Reserved7[6];
} SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION , *PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION;

extern "C" MY_API void enumCurrentprocess();
MY_API std::vector<PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION> runningprocesses;
```

and here is the funtion definition in Cpp file:

```
    MY_API void enumCurrentprocess(){
........
........
    if (NTSTATUS ntret = retval(SystemProcessInformation, SYSPI, 1024 * 1024, NULL) < 0) {
            VirtualFree(buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        }
        do {
            runningprocesses.push_back(SYSPI);
            SYSPI = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION)((LPBYTE)SYSPI + SYSPI->NextEntryOffset);
        } while (SYSPI->NextEntryOffset);
    
    
        VirtualFree(buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    }
```

i've tried that the function is works fine but whenever i export that vector,the client.exe just cant read the actual vector

in my case the GUI try to show the table based on vector size like this one

```
 enumCurrentprocess();
    ui->procList->setRowCount(runningprocesses.size());
```

it just did nothing i was thingking my pota pc was late rendering and waited until 20-30 min but it shows nothing after i change the size with normal int it works fine xD.

any help wil be so apreciated and anyway sorry for my broken englisht thanks!

Comment: It appears that the buffer at SYSPI address was released and what you store in vector `runningprocesses` needs to be SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION and not PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION so you should copy the data in the vector: `MY_API std::vector<SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION> runningprocesses;` and `runningprocesses.push_back(*SYSPI);`. The rest is just no a good style and you should rather have better interface with the function returning vector to the other DLL caller etc. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sharedlibrary.html

Comment: i've tried that before, and it just getting worst bcs that SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION is contain C code, but i will try this pointer o7

Comment: ohya i'm sorry before that it might be out of topic question but is it affected by the way i linked my dll? because currently i'm statically linked my dll to my.lib file, bcs i've tried that and nothing happen